# Recreating positional array operator with LINQ and MongoDb

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In MongoDB I have an update query that works:

```
db.posts.update(
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "Comments.Reference" : 123 
  },
  { 
    $push : 
    { 
      "Comments.$.Notes": { Text: "Some description here" } 
    }
  });
```

This finds the Post document with the matching Id, and to the Comments object with the matching reference in that array, it will push a new object into the Notes array within it.

However, as I am using C# and the driver, I wanted to see if it was possible to create this with LINQ.

Where I am falling down is creating an update query that translates to creating the $ positional operator.

```csharp
IMongoUpdate update = Update<Post>.Push(t => t.Comments.First().Notes,
                                        BsonDocument.Parse("{ Text: \"Test\"}");
```

I put the First() as a first guess and to get it to compile, however it throws an error to say that it can't serialize it.

Is it possible to recreate this, or will I just have to revert to using a string query of "Comments.$.Notes" instead?

**Edit:** Just to update, this is what works, but provides no type safety:

```csharp
IMongoUpdate update = Update.Push("Comments.$.Notes",
                                  BsonDocument.Parse("{ Text: \"Test\"}");
```

Comment: Could you share the C# for your Post class? It's been a while since I've used the Mongo C# driver, but I'll try to help if I can :)

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-531

Comment: Excellent find! I consider that as good as an answer for now Martin, it's currently unsupported. Want to promote that comment into an answer and I'll mark it as Accepted?

Comment: Gladly, thanks! ... just wish I had a better answer than "It's not supported"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality has been added:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1046

To copy directly from the jira case:

```
Builders<Entity>.Update.Set(x => x.MyArray[-1].Value, 10);
```

will yield

```
{ $set: { "MyArray.$.Value", 10 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like it is not supported at this time :(

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-531